# PHP get record in page from URL

Tags: php, mysql

I have database name is "db" Table is 'tbl_pro' is Feild are "msid" "subid" "pid" and "pname".

when I try to fetch the data through "msid" from URL it is working fine on a new page. but through "pname" I am not able to get it.   here is my code

Page 1 code:

```
<?
            $QryP=mysql_query("Select * from tbl_pro where Pname='test' order by Rank desc") or die("Error loading Products");
            if(mysql_num_rows($QryP)>0) {
            while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($QryP)){
                  ?>  
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 ">
                    <div class="w-box product">
                        <figure>
                            <img alt="" src="upload/spic/<?=$rs["Spic"]?>" class="img-responsive img-center">
                        </figure>
                        <h2><a href="test.php?Pname=<?=$rs["Pname"]?>"><?=$rs["Pname"]?></a></h2>
                                    <p>
```

on the other page its.

Page 2 code:

```
 <?
        $QryP=mysql_query("Select * from tbl_pro where Pname=".$_REQUEST["Pname"]."    AND  Display='y'" ) or die("Error loading Products");
            if(mysql_num_rows($QryP)>0) {
            while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($QryP)){

    ?>
```

if i use "msid" instead of "Pname" its working fine.

Comment: Are column names case-sensitive in MySQL? (I don't use it myself, so I don't know). - i.e. should it be "pname" (as you said at the top of your question) instead of "Pname"?

Comment: You are missing the single quotes around the value. `...Pname='".$_REQUEST["Pname"]."'...` Also in the die() print out the actual error.

Comment: Also mysql_* is deprecated. Have a look at mysqli_*

Answer (score 0):

Its better to go with the like operator when you were using a string in a query

if(isset($_REQUEST['Pname'])){$Pname=$_REQUEST['Pname'];}else{$Pname='';}

if(Pname!=''){

$QryP=mysql_query("Select * from tbl_pro where Pname like '%".$Pname."%' AND  Display='y'" ) or die("Error loading Products");